# Insertar un registro en 2 tablas relacionadas

Tags: java

```
 String cod,mod,cat,des,pre,stock;
        String sql="";
        cod=txtcod.getText();
        mod=txtmode.getText();
        cat=cboCateg.getSelectedItem().toString();
        des=txtdes.getText();
        pre=txtpre.getText();
        stock=txtstock.getText();
        sql="INSERT INTO producto (id_producto, id_categoria, modelo, descripcion, precio, stock) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";


    try {
        PreparedStatement pst  = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, cod);
        pst.setString(2, mod);
        pst.setString(3, cat);
        pst.setString(4, des);
        pst.setString(5, pre);
        pst.setString(6, stock);
        int n=pst.executeUpdate();
        if(n>0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro Guardado con Exito");
        bloquear();
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(IngresoProductos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

[[image: Mi código en java[2]]
Quisiera saber cómo puedo hacer la consulta para insertar el nombre de la categoría en mis 2 tablas

Comment: insertar en que campo de tu tabla producto se deberia insertar el nombre de la categoria?

Comment: Deberías poner el código en formato texto usando la herramienta para insertar código que tienes cuando redactas la pregunta. Si pones una imagen y el enlace se rompe, nadie podrá leer bien tu pregunta. Por otra parte, el nombre de la categoría debe estar sólo en la tabla categoría, de lo contrario la tabla categoría carecería de sentido y desnormalizarías tu base de datos.

Comment: en el nombre de la categoria

Comment: @Arthur proba con esto `INSERT INTO categoria (nombre)
VALUES ("miNombre");`

Comment: ¿Podrías decirnos qué SGBD usas y poner el código en texto y no en captura de pantalla? La respuesta corta es: se puede hacer en una transacción, pero no en una única consulta. En cuanto lo hagas te diré cómo hacerlo (dependiendo del SGDB la obtención del último identificador insertado cambia).

Comment: ya lo puse, lo siento soy nuevo en esto estoy usando el Mysql